# Скрипт определения наличия блока

Tags: javascript, css

Нужен скрипт, который будет установлен на странице `index.html` и будет на странице `/$user_id` проверять, есть ли там `<div id="reverbs5"`, если да - то применять к элементу `<div id="reverb_hov5"` который находится на странице где он установлен `(index.html)` стиль `display:none`, если нет - ничего не делать

Comment: Не понял.Это 2 разные страницы.

Comment: На необходимой странице блок может как быть,так и не быть.Вот поэтому нужна проверка.

Comment: Мм..вы не поняли суть вопроса.Прочтите внимательно и поймете

Comment: Есть страница А,на странице А есть блок который может быть,а может и не быть.Нужно на странице Б показать другой блок,в зависимости от наличия первого блока на странице А.Как-то так..

Comment: Если используете JQuery то проверять наличие элемента можно вот так $('div').has('#reverbs5'), что вернет true если он на странице есть.

Comment: @Matel а как быть если пользователь сразу зашел на страницу Б?

Comment: @Gonzo, вы могли бы дать ответ с учетом вашего комментария?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Предлагаю воспользоваться `localStorage`

на странице А:

```
localStorage.setItem("block-hide", !!document.querySelector("#reverbs5"));
```

На странице Б:

```
if (localStorage.getItem("block-hide") === "true") {
    document.querySelector("#reverb_hov5").style.display = "none"
}
```

Если необходимо динамически это проворачивать, а не только при открытии страницы - можно все это завернуть в таймеры

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99198/discussion-on-answer-by-stranger-in-the-q----).